# Icon for Request

Tags: icons, design, interface

I need to design icon for "Request a Feature" Anyone Please suggest any idea to design a icon for 'Request a Feature' context.

Comment: If I were you I would use the logo for the website/app with a little lightbulb overlaying the corner. This implies there is an idea for the site.

Answer (score 2):

"Request a feature" is quite an abstract concept so I don't think there would be a clear conventional icon to use here.

Here are my suggestions:

1. You could think about a [speech bubble](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/comment/) to represent the "request" part.

[image: Speech Bubble Icon]

A [light bulb](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/lightbulb-o/) is another one that could work as it suggests a new idea.

[image: Light Bulb Icon]

A [rocket](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/rocket/) is a bit of a strange one but could suggest innovation.

[image: Rocket Icon]

Comment: I like the bulb. The rocket has a nice concept but may be harder to grasp. The speech bubble may be a bit too generic (it can apply to any type of comment).

Comment: I agree, the light bulb communicates "feature request" better than the others. It's definitely the one I would go for.